# Replicate Excel Pivot Chart in Python

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have a dataset that has too many rows to fit inside an Excel worksheet (Excel 2016 Home and Business version). In previous datasets that had less rows I was able to create a pivot chart with lots of slicers to interactively view my data. It worked great!

Now, I have just started learning Python and I know that you can create pivot tables in Pandas. But what about pivot CHARTS? Is there a tool to create pivot charts with the same interactivity as the Excel slicers?

Many thanks

Comment: [Bokeh](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/) may be what you're looking for. This [example](https://demo.bokehplots.com/apps/stocks) displays some of the functionality I think you're describing.

Comment: Thanks, it doesn't appear to do quite what I am after. I have found a way of doing it, but it's not interactive
`table = data[(data['Depth']==10) & 
             (data['IE']==1) & 
             (data['Diameter']<10) & 
             (data['Liftoff']==7) &
             (data['Taper']==2) &
             (data['RPALimit']==10)].pivot_table(values="DetectionRate", index=["SensorSpacing"], columns=["AxialScanPitch"],aggfunc='mean')
table.plot.line()
` 
I would like a better method for filtering the data input into the pivot table. Much like the form buttons (slicers) used in Excel

Comment: I echo Bokeh, the [movie dashboard](https://demo.bokehplots.com/apps/movies) is one of the best examples, because it has so many controls that interact with each other. I, myself, used the [weather](https://demo.bokehplots.com/apps/weather) example as a basis to drill down into data. Use them as a guide, then look at the [interaction docs](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/0.10.0/docs/user_guide/interaction.html) for how to build what you want. Check boxes in particular could be useful for recreating slicers.